# Microsoft Speech Recognition defaults vs API

Tags: windows-10, speech-recognition, microsoft-speech-platform, microsoft-speech-api

So I've been using Microsoft Speech Recognition in Windows 10, doing the training exercises, dictating text into Wordpad and correcting it, adding words to the dictionary and so on. I would like to use the software to transcribe .wav files. It appears one can do this using the Windows Speech Recognition API, but this seems to involve creating and loading one's own grammar files, which suggests to me that this would basically create a new speech recognizer, that uses the same building blocks but is a different program from the one that runs when I click "Start Speech Recognition" in the start menu. In particular, it would perform differently because of differences in training or configuration.

Am I wrong in this ? And if I'm not, is there still a way of retrieving all the data the default speech recognizer uses so I can reproduce its behavior exactly? If I need to create a separate speech recognizer with its own grammar files and separate training history and so on in order to transcribe .wav files then so be it but I'd like to better understand what's going on here.

Comment: Are you talking about the differences between different `Constraint`s of a `SpeechRecognizer`? I can't understand what you want to do, but when you don’t specify any constraints for your ‘SpeechRecognizer’ object, the predefined dictation grammar(SpeechRecognitionTopicConstrant) will be used as default.

Answer (score 0):

The [Woundify](https://github.com/BSalita/Woundify/) open source project contains examples of how to convert wav files and to text (STT).